# Enter China (from European Union), after being fined in Hong Kong a few years ago

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china, hong-kong, fines

I got fined 3 years ago in Hong Kong for dropping a cigarette butt on the ground. I never paid that fine, and I wonder if I would have problems when entering Mainland China due to that fact.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes? This seems like a perfectly reasonable question. One question I have for the OP: Do you have a valid (Mainland) Chinese visa right now?

Comment: My final destination is another asian country, but I transit at Beijing airport for 20h, so I was planning to visit the city with no visa, since its possible for less than 72h...

Answer (score 6):

No, you wouldn't. Hong Kong and China are two different jurisdictions, on which HK law does not apply to China, and vice versa (with exceptions).
Anyway, you should pay that fine in someday so that you don't have any trouble when you will visit HK in the future.